# what happens when a biomarker patent was filed based on wrong science?

Tags: science, biomarker

What happens if a patent for a specific biomarker (e.g. list of genes or genomic markers) was successfully filed, but later on discovered it was based on the wrong Science?

Would that still preclude other people from filing that specific biomarker given new correct scientific evidence?

Answer (score 1):

**Would that still preclude other people from filing that specific biomarker given new correct scientific evidence?**

You haven't cited a specific patent so this will have to be a general answer. Also, I should point out that I'm not an attorney so this is just merely based upon the observations of an inventor. I've found that there seems to be no burden to prove that an invention works or that the science behind it is sound. Some might argue that if a worthless invention is granted, no one is harmed since no one would want to practice it. Your question is a bit different in that it implies that the use of the specific biomarker in the way patented actually works, but that the science presented in the specification is flawed. I don't think it matters that the scientific theory of operation is flawed if the patent has been granted. What matters is that the invention actually works and has value. After all, the inventor could have stated that the biomarker is indicative of medical condition "A" but we don't know why it works. Indeed, this might be helpful in the prosecution of the patent since it argues against obviousness.

So, as far as I know, you can't just try to claim the same use in a new patent just because you now know why it works. Hopefully, your greater scientific insight will allow you to find different indications for the specific biomarker to patent. It is quite possible that there is patent case law I'm unaware of, so I would encourage an actual patent attorney to weigh in on this question.